# Docker discovery server and client API Java Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

I have a docker compose with this:

```
  ## Eureka Server
  discovery-server:
    image: carlosbrrs/discovery-server:latest
    container_name: discovery-server
    ports:
      - "8761:8761"
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
  #    depends_on:
  #      - zipkin

  api-gateway:
    image: carlosbrrs/api-gateway:latest
    container_name: api-gateway
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    expose:
      - "8080"
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
      - LOGGING_LEVEL_ORG_SPRINGFRAMEWORK_SECURITY=TRACE
      - EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICEURL_DEFAULTZONE=http://discovery-server:8761/eureka
    depends_on:
      #      - zipkin
      - discovery-server
      - keycloak

  ## Product-Service Docker Compose Config
  product-service:
    container_name: product-service
    image: carlosbrrs/product-service:latest
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
    depends_on:
      - mongo
      - discovery-server
      - api-gateway

  ## Order-Service Docker Compose Config
  order-service:
    container_name: order-service
    image: carlosbrrs/order-service:latest
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgres-order:5431/order-service
    depends_on:
      - postgres-order
      - kafka
      #      - zipkin
      - discovery-server
      - api-gateway

  ## Inventory-Service Docker Compose Config
  inventory-service:
    container_name: inventory-service
    image: carlosbrrs/inventory-service:latest
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgres-inventory:5432/inventory-service
    depends_on:
      - postgres-inventory
      - discovery-server
      - api-gateway

  ## Notification-Service Docker Compose Config
  notification-service:
    container_name: notification-service
    image: carlosbrrs/notification-service:latest
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
    depends_on:
      #      - zipkin
      - kafka
      - discovery-server
      - api-gateway
```

And the application.properties for discovery-server is:

```
server.port=8761

eureka.instance.hostname=discovery-server
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
#eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://discovery-server:8761/eureka

eureka.username=${EUREKA_USERNAME:eureka}
eureka.password=${EUREKA_PASSWORD:password}

spring.security.basic.enabled=true
spring.security.user.name=eureka
spring.security.user.password=password
```

for api-gateway is:

```
server.port=8080
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://eureka:password@discovery-server:8761/eureka
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri= http://keycloak:8181/realms/spring-boot-microservices-realm
app.eureka-server=discovery-server
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
eureka.client.registry-with-eureka=true
```

I haven't go through the rest of services, I want to solve first api-gateway but is throwing this error:

```
2023-12-29T21:35:39.091Z  INFO 1 --- [api-gateway] [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_API-GATEWAY/api-gateway:94d5d7e73b900fba27e25eddd3374ffc: registering service...
2023-12-29T21:35:39.234534359Z 2023-12-29T21:35:39.233Z  WARN 1 --- [api-gateway] [nfoReplicator-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failure with status code 401; retrying on another server if available
2023-12-29T21:35:39.236410925Z 2023-12-29T21:35:39.234Z  WARN 1 --- [api-gateway] [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_API-GATEWAY/api-gateway:94d5d7e73b900fba27e25eddd3374ffc - registration failed Cannot execute request on any known server
2023-12-29T21:35:39.236482804Z 
2023-12-29T21:35:39.236498185Z com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server

c.n.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator     : There was a problem with the instance info replicator


 c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failure with status code 401; retrying on another server if available
2023-12-29T21:36:08.780423430Z 2023-12-29T21:36:08.778Z  INFO 1 --- [api-gateway] [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_API-GATEWAY/api-gateway:94d5d7e73b900fba27e25eddd3374ffc - was unable to refresh its cache! This periodic background refresh will be retried in 30 seconds. status = Cannot execute request on any known server stacktrace = com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
```

Any suggestions? After solve api-gateway I will be able to replicate the solution in other services